# pnpm use docker volume as store path

Tags: docker, pnpm

I want to use a single directory as shared cache directory for multiple Jenkins pipelines.

So I use a command like this to run scripts:

```bash
docker run --rm \
    -v $HOME:$HOME -e HOME \
    -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD \
    pnpm pnpm install-and-build
```

I found pnpm created a .pnpm-store directory in `$PWD` rather than `$HOME/.pnpm-store`.

I found the reason is pnpm uses `hard link` as the underlying mechanism which does not support cross device link.

What can I do to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Its interesting!!!!
I'm just thinking shared pnpm store on docker.

How about try
''pnpm config set store-dir /path/to/.pnpm-store''

setting custom store dir then your problem seems like will be solved.